# Best way to position over image

Tags: css, image, html, position

I got a navigation menu as image. I made a nav div with the image as background and a fixed width and height. Now in the little boxes under the lines I want nav links. So what I did is I made multiple divs in the nav div and positioned them in the little boxes. So they are all positioned perfectly inside firefox but, unfortunately in other browsers like chrome they have different positions (nothing extreme, but they arent perfectly aligned in the little boxes).

[image: nav]

What I thought was that whenever you have a certain fixed height and width of the container div. The margins of the child divs will be the same on all browsers and screen sizes as they will always be the same size. How is this possible and what would be the best options to make this nav menu possible?

Comment: Are you using a CSS reset? That generally helps with browser margin inconsistencies. [Eric Meyer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) is a good one.

Comment: may this helps you to understand why it is like what it is http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/3706370.htm

Comment: Fonts also render slightly differently on different browser / operating systems. So the sizes of the children could change because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use this http://www.image-maps.com/  ... image maping tool lets you to set link coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

If you know where these boxes are located pixel-wise in the background image, you could absolute position the nav divs and get them precisely where you want using top and left based on pixels of the parent div (with the image) instead of using margins.